# What is the differce between Streams and Sockets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, networking

Guys what is the difference between **Streams** and **Sockets** in Flutter and when to use them?

I'm going to use Flutter in mobile app(iOS/Android) and the app is going to receive continuous flow of data coming from server, so now I'm confuced what to choose for this purpose.
*Note that performance is important.

Comment: I think that this question is too broad because `Stream` and `Socket` are very general classes. [Seed Nabil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59703753/6509751) is helpful. You can take a look at the [`Socket` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Socket-class.html) and you will notice that it implements `Stream`. The problem with your question is that you cannot just "use" `Socket` or `Stream` - you will have to find a networking API that provides e.g. a socket. You can learn more about streams in Dart [here](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams).

Answer (score 5):

`Sockets` is a real time technology related to server side which enables your back-end to push data to your client side without the need for continuous polling your server.

`Streams` in flutter is an object that hold reference to changing data that you can tap into it and react to the change.

these are two different concepts but they normally combined together to give you the reactive behavior wanted for your app.

hope that help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also went to the documentation of Streams as suggested by @creativecreatorormaybenot and found them explainig Streams as something related to user generated data not Client &Server data. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, @abdullah